# How to properly train a model for OCR with CreateML? Mine is not just bad, it is utterly worthless

Tags: ocr, coreml, createml

I created a dataset with 1 generated training image per letter and about 10 real-life test images per letter.

All of them are 10x14px, black&white (nicely binarized in preprocessing stage).

The resulting model recognizes all symbols as '1' (even the actual images from the testing set), so basically it is not working at all.

Who can point me in the right direction?

Here's the CreateML output -

```html
Extracting image features from full data set.
Analyzing and extracting image features.
+------------------+--------------+------------------+
| Images Processed | Elapsed Time | Percent Complete |
+------------------+--------------+------------------+
| 1                | 1.74s        | 2.5%             |
| 2                | 1.96s        | 5.25%            |
| 3                | 2.17s        | 8%               |
| 4                | 2.39s        | 10.75%           |
| 5                | 2.60s        | 13.5%            |
| 10               | 3.68s        | 27%              |
| 25               | 6.90s        | 67.5%            |
| 37               | 9.48s        | 100%             |
| 36               | 9.26s        | 97.25%           |
+------------------+--------------+------------------+
Skipping automatic creation of validation set; training set has fewer than 50 points.
Beginning model training on processed features. 
Calibrating solver; this may take some time.
+-----------+--------------+-------------------+
| Iteration | Elapsed Time | Training Accuracy |
+-----------+--------------+-------------------+
| 0         | 0.038845     | 0.027027          |
| 1         | 0.139269     | 0.837838          |
| 2         | 0.268821     | 0.945946          |
| 3         | 0.317312     | 0.945946          |
| 4         | 0.367944     | 0.972973          |
| 5         | 0.422657     | 0.972973          |
| 10        | 0.713325     | 1.000000          |
| 24        | 1.495230     | 1.000000          |
+-----------+--------------+-------------------+
SUCCESS: Optimal solution found.
Extracting image features from evaluation data.
Analyzing and extracting image features.
+------------------+--------------+------------------+
| Images Processed | Elapsed Time | Percent Complete |
+------------------+--------------+------------------+
| 1                | 211.661ms    | 0.25%            |
| 2                | 425.538ms    | 0.75%            |
| 3                | 641.33ms     | 1.25%            |
| 4                | 861.215ms    | 1.75%            |
| 5                | 1.07s        | 2.25%            |
| 10               | 2.16s        | 4.75%            |
| 25               | 5.39s        | 12%              |
| 50               | 10.75s       | 24%              |
| 75               | 16.12s       | 36%              |
| 100              | 21.51s       | 48%              |
| 125              | 26.88s       | 60%              |
| 150              | 32.24s       | 72%              |
| 175              | 37.61s       | 84%              |
| 200              | 42.97s       | 96%              |
| 208              | 44.69s       | 100%             |
| 207              | 44.47s       | 99.5%            |
+------------------+--------------+------------------+
Trained model successfully saved at /mypath/ocr.mlmodel.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. OCR is hard.
2. You don't have nearly enough training examples.
3. Create ML uses a "feature extractor" that is very powerful. This also means it's really easy to the model to simply memorize all your training data since the images are really small and you only have a couple of them. There is not much you can do with Create ML to prevent this from happening.
4. Try training a simple logistic regression on your data using a package such as scikit-learn. It will work much better than a deep neural network.

Comment: Thanks Matthijs! Would you please elaborate on #2 - how many examples should I have if I need only one particular font, and whether they should be generated from the font (i.e. reference images) or real-life ones? and #4 - is scikit-learn the only option for that, or is it also doable with tensorflow and turi-create? and if so, would you please give a more specific advice as what to use in TF/TC?

Comment: Deep learning models usually need 100s or 1000s of images per category you want them to learn. 10x14 pixels is also very small. 224x224 is more typical. You could use TF or TC to train a logistic regression indeed. In scikit-learn it's only a few lines of code and it's not hard to learn. But in Turi it's also just a few lines of code and it can immediately write a Core ML file.

Comment: Perfect, that's all I need!

Comment: Note that I only suggested logistic regression because you have so little data. Usually for learning from pixel-based data, i.e. images, a convolutional neural network gives much better results than logistic regression. But the convnets provided by Create ML and Turi Create are overkill for your data, which is why you get such bad results. Training a logistic regression is a good first step, but you eventually may want to train your own (small) convnet in Keras or TensorFlow.

Comment: Indeed I concern myself only with a single font of a specific size - for now, at least. I actually have three more questions for you if you don't mind: 1. does it make sense to use reference images generated from the font itself (i.e. not scanned, but pixel-perfect ones), and if so, how? 2. what feature extraction mechanism should I use to feed the images to logistic regression? (in TC/TF) and 3. CreateML does have a logistic regression classifier, could there be a way to feed images to it somehow?

Comment: 1. A typical trick is to generate lots and lots of images using the font, but to distort them in all kinds of creative ways. 2. Initially you wouldn't use a feature extractor, i.e. use the pixels as the features. Should work reasonably well for small images. 3. You will probably need to flatten the images and provide them as an MLDataTable.

Comment: Thanks! I will start with #3 then and see whether it yields something promising.

Comment: Check out how Dropbox tries to solve this problem. They generate noisy sample images from text with GAN  to create a dataset and then use combination of several deep neural networks (LSTM,CNN etc) https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2017/04/creating-a-modern-ocr-pipeline-using-computer-vision-and-deep-learning/